# OutOfMemoryError reading a huge ZipFile

Tags: java, android, out-of-memory, zip

I'm trying to open a big (around 1 GiB) zip file in Android using `java.util.zip` API and get the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.util.HashMap.makeTable(HashMap.java:555)
at java.util.HashMap.doubleCapacity(HashMap.java:575)
at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:405)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.readCentralDir(ZipFile.java:366)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:132)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:103)
at com.foo.bar.zip.archive.ZipArchive.<init>(ZipArchive.java:44)
```

I completely understand that the size of the file exceeds the memory limit by a big margin, but is there any workaround for the issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the problem is not the size of the file but the number of entries as it is failing when caching the Zip table entries.

Your own options are to;

- break up the Zip so it doesn't have so many files in it.
- get more memory
- write your own library for reading the ZIP.

Comment: Nice list of options for sure. Anyway, thanks for making it clear!

Answer (score 4):

The Java classes `ZipFile` and `ZipEntry` can't contain anything that is more then 613 MB of memory.

It's probably best to implement some sort of batching as you propose yourself. You could for example add up the decompressed size of each ZIP entry and upload the files every time the total size exceeds 100 MB.

Take a look at: http://truezip.java.net/

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to be able to extract particular entries from the zip file by name, or can you just read through the whole file once from top to bottom?  If the latter you could try using `ZipInputStream` rather than `ZipFile`, as that doesn't need to parse the central directory up front - you can read one entry, do something with it, discard it, read the next entry, ...

Comment: I have a bunch of options for an archive: listing the files, extracting them all, extracting some of them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to read your file in byte arrays and partially work over it. Still it depends on what do you want to do with your file.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link for download and extract zip files, it will solve your problem.

For Downloading Zip File:-

[Download Zip File](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1521)

For Extract Zip File:-

[Extract Zip File](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

And the zip file is make using winrar software only otherwise this will give you error.

Comment: Your first link is about downloading any file, not just ZIP files. Winrar isn't mentioned on either page. Second link uses ZipInputStream, which can read files produced by WinZip, PKZIP, ZipOutputStream, and a host of other things as well as Winrar, so I have no idea what you're talking about there.